# Task @Sendable operation

Tags: swift, async-await, swift-concurrency

Writing a simple code:

```swift
class App {
    private var value = 0
    
    func start() async throws {
        await withTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in
            for _ in 1...100 {
                group.addTask(operation: self.increment) // 1
                
                group.addTask {
                    await self.increment() // 2
                }
                
                group.addTask {
                    self.value += 1 // 3
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    @Sendable private func increment() async {
        self.value += 1 // 4
    }
}
```

I got compile time warnings at lines 2, 3:
`Capture of 'self' with non-sendable type 'App' in a @Sendable closure`

However with enabled Thread Sanitizer, and removed lines 2 and 3, I got ThreadSanitizer runtime warning at line 4:
`Swift access race in (1) suspend resume partial function for asyncTest.App.increment@Sendable () async -> () at 0x106003c80`

So I have questions:

1. What is the difference between using these 3 .addTask ways?
2. What does @Sendable attribute does?
3. How can I make increment() function thread safe (data race free)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For illustration of how to achieve thread-safety, consider:

```swift
class Counter {
    private var value = 0

    func incrementManyTimes() async {
        await withTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in
            for _ in 1...1_000_000 {
                group.addTask {
                    self.increment()                                  // no `await` as this is not `async` method
                }
            }

            await group.waitForAll()

            if value != 1_000_000 {
                print("not thread-safe apparently; value =", value)   // not thread-safe apparently; value = 994098
            } else {
                print("ok")
            }
        }
    }

    private func increment() {                                        // note, this isn't `async` (as there is no `await` suspension point in here)
        value += 1
    }
}
```

That illustrates that it is not thread-safe, validating the warning from TSAN. (Note, I bumped the iteration count to make it easier to manifest the symptoms of non-thread-safe code.)

So, how would you make it thread-safe? Use an actor:

```swift
actor Counter {
    private var value = 0

    func incrementManyTimes() async {
        await withTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in
            for _ in 1...1_000_000 {
                group.addTask {
                    await self.increment()
                }
            }

            await group.waitForAll()

            if value != 1_000_000 {
                print("not thread-safe apparently; value =", value)
            } else {
                print("ok")                                           // ok
            }
        }
    }

    private func increment() {                                        // note, this still isn't `async`
        value += 1
    }
}
```

If you really want to use a class, add your own old-school synchronization. Here I am using a lock, but you could use a serial GCD queue, or whatever you want.

```swift
class Counter {
    private var value = 0
    let lock = NSLock()

    func incrementManyTimes() async {
        await withTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in
            for _ in 1...1_000_000 {
                group.addTask {
                    self.increment()
                }
            }

            await group.waitForAll()

            if value != 1_000_000 {
                print("not thread-safe apparently; value =", value)
            } else {
                print("ok")                                           // ok
            }
        }
    }

    private func increment() {
        lock.withLock {
            value += 1
        }
    }
}
```

Or, if you want to make `Counter` a `Sendable` type, too, confident that you are properly doing the synchronization yourself, like above, you can declare it as `final` and declare that it is `Sendable`, admittedly `@unchecked` by the compiler:

```swift
final class Counter: @unchecked Sendable {
    private var value = 0
    let lock = NSLock()

    func incrementManyTimes() async {
        // same as above
    }

    private func increment() {
        lock.withLock {
            value += 1
        }
    }
}
```

But because the compiler cannot possibly reason about the actual “sendability” itself, you have to designate this as a `@unchecked Sendable` to let it know that you personally have verified it is really `Sendable`.

But `actor` is the preferred mechanism for ensuring thread-safety, eliminating the need for this custom synchronization logic.

---

For more information, see WWDC 2021 video [Protect mutable state with Swift actors](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10133/) or 2022’s [Eliminate data races using Swift Concurrency](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/110351).

See `Sendable` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sendable/) for a discussion of what the `@Sendable` attribute does.

---

BTW, I suspect you know this, but for the sake of future readers, while `increment` is fine for illustrative purposes, it is not a good candidate for parallelism. This parallelized rendition is actually slower than a simple, single-threaded solution. To achieve performance gains of parallelism, you need to have enough work on each thread to justify the modest overhead that parallelism entails.

Also, when testing parallelism, be wary of using the simulator, which significantly/artificially constrains the cooperative thread pool used by Swift concurrency. Test on macOS target, or a physical device. Neither the simulator nor a playground is a good testbed for this sort of parallelism exercise.

Comment: In documentation about @Sendable attribute I saw: `Any values that the function or closure captures must be sendable.` But why I can make `increment()` function as @Sendable without any compiler warnings? And pass it in `addTask` method without warnings?

Comment: And I can even add non-Sendable parameters to function: `increment(nonSendableObject: MyObject)` and mark it as `@Sendable` without any compiler warnings

Comment: Yeah, the sendability checking is not perfect. It is a work in progress. But the key take home for thread-safety is that you should use an actor, or synchronize it yourself. You could submit [feedback](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/) regarding the lack of warnings in line #1 if you want. But the compile-time error messages for #2 and #3 look correct to my eyes. And check out the “Swift Concurrency” build setting, in which you can request “minimal”, “targeted”, or “complete” checking. And, as I said, it is a work-in-progress.